# soup.select('.r a') in 'https://www.google.com/#q=vigilante+mic' gives empty list in python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract all links from google search results page.
here's the snippet of the code:

```
    import requests,bs4

    res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/#q=vigilante+mic')

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

    linkElem = soup.select('.r a')
```

But soup.select('.r a') is returning an empty list

Thanks

Comment: What does ('.r a') represents?

Comment: When the question was asked "r" is the class name for the result containing div and "a" is the anchor tag. soup.select('.r a') will select all the element with class "r" and inside that the anchor ("a") tag to get the results. P.S. The question was asked in 2016 and now google might have changed class name for the result. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the url you are using:

https://www.google.com/#q=vigilante+mic

Is a javascript version of the search. If you `curl` it you will see there are no answers in the html. This happens because the results are fetched through javascript and requests doesn't handle that.

Try this other url (that is not javascript based):

https://www.google.com/search?q=vigilante+mic

Now it works:

```
import requests,bs4

res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=vigilante+mic')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

linkElem = soup.select('.r a')
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

Besides changing `#q=` to `?q=`, one of the reasons it's empty is because there's no `user-agent` specified thus Google blocks your request. [What is my user-agent?](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Title-Link-Snippet-python#main.py) that scrapes more:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {'q': 'cyber security'}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# container with all needed data
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(link)

----------
'''
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/what-is-cybersecurity.html
https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/cybersecurity
https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/definitions/what-is-cyber-security
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security
https://www.cisa.gov/cybersecurity
https://onlinedegrees.und.edu/blog/types-of-cyber-security-threats/
https://digitalguardian.com/blog/what-cyber-security
https://staysafeonline.org/
'''
```

Alternatively, you can achieve this by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you only need to iterate over JSON string without figuring out how to extract something or find `CSS` that works.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "cyber security",
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
    link = result['link']
    print(link)

-----------------
'''
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/what-is-cybersecurity.html
https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/cybersecurity
https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/definitions/what-is-cyber-security
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security
https://www.cisa.gov/cybersecurity
https://onlinedegrees.und.edu/blog/types-of-cyber-security-threats/
https://digitalguardian.com/blog/what-cyber-security
https://staysafeonline.org/
'''
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more detailed blog post about how to scrape [Google Organic Search Results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.