# soup.select('.r a') returns an empty list?

Tags: python, webbrowser-control

I am trying to build a program to select at most 5 search result, search them in google and open it up in the browser. However, "soup.select('.r a')" in the program returns an empty list.

```
import requests
import sys
import webbrowser
import bs4
res=requests.get('http://google.com/search?q='+'Python'.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
linkElements=soup.select('.r a')
linkToOpen=min(5,len(linkElements))
for i in range(linkToOpen):
    webbrowser.open('https//google.com'+linkElements[i].get('href'))
```

The code runs without any error and without any output but does not open the browser with search results as it was supposed to do.

Comment: JavaScript changes the classes once the HTML loads. If you don't the HTML you download with requests, you'll most likely see that it doesn't match what you inspect in a browser.

Comment: I am really sorry but I am new to programming. I would really appreciate if you can explain a little more about it. And is there a way around? Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: This question has been asked before, you'll find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56664934/soup-select-r-a-in-fhttps-google-com-searchq-query-brings-back-empty

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I tried the solution suggested by Aravind but it does not seem to be working. It again returns an empty list!

Answer (score 0):

The page uses heavy Javascript, so what you get through `request` isn't exactly what you see in your browser. You could use this script to **scrape** search links from the page (it will search for all links where `href` begins with `/url?q=`):

```
import requests
import bs4

res=requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=Python')
res.raise_for_status()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

for a in soup.select('a[href^="/url?q="]'):
    if 'accounts.google.com' in a['href']:
        continue
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
/url?q=https://www.python.org/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiCivuzmMDjAhVtxMQBHWfIBxYQFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3TQfZO4gqXrTLm27x1qkJF
/url?q=https://www.python.org/downloads/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiCivuzmMDjAhVtxMQBHWfIBxYQjBAwAXoECAcQAw&usg=AOvVaw1ktQJcwOoHkm6N4OpYlgA-
/url?q=https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiCivuzmMDjAhVtxMQBHWfIBxYQjBAwAnoECAcQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1DkCjMJbFGfNpiQw1qDBWB
/url?q=https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiCivuzmMDjAhVtxMQBHWfIBxYQjBAwA3oECAcQBw&usg=AOvVaw1ih35T-Enlb7d32gyyNGvc
...and so on.
```