# Taking all <a> tags from <div> tags with a specific class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was working on debugging and getting the lucky.py code in "automate the boring stuff with python to work." The primary problem here is that the author's code isn't working (outdated probably). The code is aimed at passing a command-line argument while executing a python script. The script opens the first five (or less) Google search results for the argument in new tabs. Now, the original code extracts all  tags with the 'r' class. However, now, instead of using the 'r' class for search result hyperlinks, google simply encases the selfsame  tag in a div with the 'r' class.

This is what the original code did

```
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' +' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

I've tried taking all the  tags encased directly within divs, but I can't find any method to extract all  tags encased directly within 'r' class  tags.

Here are some things I have thought of, but they don't work properly.

```
linkElems = soup.select('.r div > a')
```

and this, as all  tags that I want have ping attributes that begin with '\url.'

```
 linkElems = soup.select('a')
 for link in linkElems:
     if link.attrs.hget('ping').startswith('\\url'):
         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR** : Google sends a different HTML response when running it from a python script.

Well if you actually print the `linkElems` variable you will see that it is empty. I think the reason for this is that Gooogle changes their HTML based on a lot of HTTP headers. In layman terms, this means that the HTML you see in the browser is not what you will get while running a get request from Python.

For now you can use `linkElems = soup.select('.jfp3ef > a')` and this will work just fine. It will select all the `<a>` tags that are immediate children of elements with the class `.jfp3ef`. The `.jfp3ef` class is what Google seems to be using instead of `r` when doing a request from python. But I would not put this in production because it might change from time to time.

A better and more reliable solution is to use the [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). But since you are doing this for the sake of learning, the hack I mentioned above should be fine.

**Code :**

```
import bs4
import requests

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=test')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
linkElems = soup.select('.jfp3ef > a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    print('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

**Output :**

```
http://google.com/url?q=https://www.speedtest.net/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjP9eumr97jAhX2GLkGHbGoDuoQFjAKegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw0mhIK0jUq5fUfhEJTuA90h
http://google.com/url?q=https://fast.com/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjP9eumr97jAhX2GLkGHbGoDuoQFjALegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw3WERIy0Wo_UNyqmNAVBCeZ
http://google.com/url?q=https://openspeedtest.com/Get-widget.php&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjP9eumr97jAhX2GLkGHbGoDuoQFjAMegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw1161mhQBhD75gfmsIzzg4n
http://google.com/url?q=https://www.meter.net/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjP9eumr97jAhX2GLkGHbGoDuoQFjANegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2Z3xTSmhoxz6VS7MYAaS2x
http://google.com/url?q=https://speedtest.telstra.com/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjP9eumr97jAhX2GLkGHbGoDuoQFjAOegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw36SosexF66e8fQUWIG14mZ
```

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "class name"}):
    for a in div.find_all("a", {"class": "r"}):
        print(a.attrs['href'])
```

you can get all `tags name` with `find_all()` function and if you want to get all `tags` with specific `attribute` you should send another `dict` as input to `find_all()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the article seems outdated. There aren't any tags with class `r` (at least in my case) but you can still select links by `href` attribute.

For selecting all `<a>` tags with `href` attribute that starts with `/url` you can use CSS selector `a[href^="/url"]`.

```
import bs4
import requests

search_term = 'tree'

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + search_term)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

for link in soup.select('a[href^="/url"]'):
    print(link['href'])
```

Prints:

```
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj4iMW3rN7jAhWJxMQBHag1Cr4QFjAGegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3paXH3cMIxBpu9X0bAY3mR
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_line&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj4iMW3rN7jAhWJxMQBHag1Cr4Q0gIwBnoECAcQAg&usg=AOvVaw3ynJgH_Bbw1mSqAL8ovO7e
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(disambiguation)&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj4iMW3rN7jAhWJxMQBHag1Cr4Q0gIwBnoECAcQAw&usg=AOvVaw1Dcz4l8mkB9jZHqeJKT9B9
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Trees&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj4iMW3rN7jAhWJxMQBHag1Cr4Q0gIwBnoECAcQBA&usg=AOvVaw0mZS3EU93_a96SpiqfFG-R
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-Tree&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj4iMW3rN7jAhWJxMQBHag1Cr4Q0gIwBnoECAcQBQ&usg=AOvVaw2lq87vNdcDmw0tCZxeIs_E

... and so on.
```

EDIT: To filter out IMG links and internal accounts you can do this:

```
for link in soup.select('a[href^="/url"]'):
    if link.find('img'):
        continue
    if 'accounts.google.com' in link['href']:
        continue
    print(link['href'])
```

Prints:

```
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjAGegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw213y4pDofhSr3-AzbeN6Xe
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_line&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwBnoECAMQAg&usg=AOvVaw0qQCjrcrP6YHGLeeSvYkN1
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(disambiguation)&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwBnoECAMQAw&usg=AOvVaw2OSqEJ_jRM_ByhjfvMSzjC
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Trees&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwBnoECAMQBA&usg=AOvVaw1Xh2A4mp3beT6zQNzS8aJD
/url?q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-Tree&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwBnoECAMQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1ARsOn-3cMHsILu_-1AF-Q
/url?q=https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjAHegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw3J9VoAcyvn01DK6VQjQOcJ
/url?q=https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree%23Parts_of_trees&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwB3oECAgQAg&usg=AOvVaw3uiAZjYQTYR02__Da6xkHi
/url?q=https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree%23Records&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwB3oECAgQAw&usg=AOvVaw2jexFkOqkPQ3bHZ1q1KdKj
/url?q=https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree%23Tree_value_estimation&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwB3oECAgQBA&usg=AOvVaw3URu63Yk-j0o-G75SSaeW3
/url?q=https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree%23Tree_climbing&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQ0gIwB3oECAgQBQ&usg=AOvVaw2YmeOvTuDS2cacWiM7Fzj6
/url?q=https://www.royalparks.org.uk/parks/the-regents-park/things-to-see-and-do/gardens-and-landscapes/tree-map/why-trees-are-important&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjAIegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0uk4ZAk22_zyuVRPmGGEae
/url?q=https://www.homedepot.com/b/Outdoors-Garden-Center-Trees-Bushes/N-5yc1vZc8rq&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjAJegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1v36Vzsvx9s-0BPWGp3QrH
/url?q=https://www.britannica.com/plant/tree&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjAKegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw101wIJj19V4TEj57BCA7Xe
/url?q=https://www.nparks.gov.sg/trees&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjALegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw3CDs1obwYNKnMwtMK2RBbG
/url?q=https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tree&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjAMegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3AJJuZ5vY3I8TqOSfKtVa4
/url?q=https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-47541491&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjANegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1d2QTAZ5JYAB9t6f11VY-_
/url?q=https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/jul/29/ethiopia-plants-250m-trees-in-a-day-to-help-tackle-climate-crisis&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9KPsN7jAhXwxcQBHb7eDcIQFjAOegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0c6bDr70Km_E8v3wmey124
```

Comment: This is not the right answer as it will give you all the hyperlinks on a given page some of which may not even be search results

Comment: @DollarAkshay You can filter the results more, see my edit.

Comment: Its still not quite right. The first 4 results are pointing to the same domain. If you check it in a browser it's the 4 intra-domain hyperlinks that google provides.

Comment: @DollarAkshay But that depends on use case - you can filter the links more based on domain. Or not, if you want all the links.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```py
# [0:5] - grab first 5 results
links = soup.select('.tF2Cxc .yuRUbf a')[0:5]
for link in links:
  # identical to parsing ['ping'] attribute
  print(f"http://google.com/url?q={link['href']}") # prints 5 links
```

You can use [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method which has a build-in [`limit` argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-limit-argument):

```py
links = soup.find_all('div', 'tF2Cxc', limit=5)
for link in links:
  # goes to <a> tag and grabs href attribute
  # identical parsing ['ping'] attribute
  link_elem = f"http://google.com/url?q={link.a['href']}"
  print(link_elem) # prints 5 links
```

Also, the second problem that might appear is because there's no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified thus Google will block a request and you'll receive a completely different HTML with different selectors since the [default `requests` `user-agent` is `python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814).

---

Try to use request URL [`params`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), it's more readable:

```py
# hard to read and could confuse people 
requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' +' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))

# try this instead
params = {
  "q": "The most amazing query of 2021",   # query
  "hl": "en"                               # language
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", params=params)
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "My query goes here"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

links = soup.select('.tF2Cxc .yuRUbf a')[0:5]
for link in links:
  print(f"http://google.com/url?q={link['href']}") # prints 5 links

---------
'''
http://google.com/url?q=https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html
http://google.com/url?q=https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/
http://google.com/url?q=https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/
http://google.com/url?q=https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/sql-tutorial-introduction
http://google.com/url?q=https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-sub-queries/
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't need to figure out how to scrape certain elements or how to bypass blocks from Google if they appear since it's already done for the end-user. All that needs to be done is to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "My query goes here",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# [0:5] - grab first 5 results
for result in results["organic_results"][0:5]:
  print(f"http://google.com/url?q={result['link']}")

---------
'''
http://google.com/url?q=https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html
http://google.com/url?q=https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/
http://google.com/url?q=https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/
http://google.com/url?q=https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/sql-tutorial-introduction
http://google.com/url?q=https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-sub-queries/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.